# Tool to open a UPVC window shootbolt

Tags: windows, identify-a-tool

I've got a broken UPVC window - the mechanism has broken so there is no way to get the bolts open.

All the threads and videos I've seen suggest pulling out the seal and using an allen key to force the bolt open. My problem is that the allen keys I have that are long enough are too big (in diameter) to get between the catch and the frame so I can push the bolt.

Does anyone have any other ideas on how I can get the bolt open? I wondered if there is a specialist tool that window repair people buy.

Comment: Please post some photos

Comment: Maybe figure out the largest size Allen key that will fit, then go to the store to buy one that size but longer? You may have to get a whole set, but they do sell the things in a wide variety of sizes, and you never know when you might need another long one.